# Mongo remove duplicates in array of objects based on field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

New to Mongo, have found lots of examples of removing dupes from arrays of strings using the aggregation framework, but am wondering if possible to remove dupes from array of objects based on a field in the object. Eg

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e82661d164941779c2380ca"),
"name" : "something",
"values" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "val" : "x"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "val" : "x"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "val" : "y"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "val" : "xxxxxx"
    }
]
}
```

Here I'd like to remove dupes based on the `id` field. So would end up with

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e82661d164941779c2380ca"),
"name" : "something",
"values" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "val" : "x"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "val" : "y"
    }
]
}
```

Picking the first/any object with given id works. Just want to end up with one per id. Is this doable in aggregation framework? Or even outside aggregation framework, just looking for a clean way to do this. Need to do this type of thing across many documents in collection, which seems like a good use case for aggregation framework, but as I mentioned, newbie here...thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you may get desired result 2 ways.

## Classic

Flatten - Remove duplicates (pick first occurrence) - Group by

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$values"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$values.id",
      values: {
        $first: "$values"
      },
      id: {
        $first: "$_id"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      values: {
        $push: "$values"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sd4G0MQacS9)

## Modern

We need to use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) operator.

Pseudocode:

```
values : {
  var tmp = [];
  for (var value in values) {
      if !(value.id in tmp)
        tmp.push(value);
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      values: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$values",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$this.id",
                      "$$value.id"
                    ]
                  },
                  [],
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/goMDG4rET0U)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any difference/preference between "classic" and "modern" in terms of performance or dealing with large collections?

Comment: @chacmool Need to try. If you would like to see a benchmark, let me know.

Comment: Love reacts only <3

Comment: I get the error undefined variable for "value" where are we defining value?

Comment: @JayHaran `$$value` and `$$this` are reserved variables for `$reduce` operator. If you iterate an array, `$$this` is iterating item, while `$$value` is last stored item

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html), Try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      values: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$values",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: ["$$this.id", "$$value.id"] }, /** Check if 'id' exists in holding array if yes push same array or concat holding array with & array of new object */
              "$$value",
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfuoSc1K3vK)

Comment: Was typing the explanation :D

Comment: @Valijon : did not get what you're saying ?

Comment: I was posting the same solution and was writing the explanation. But you've posted first

Comment: @Valijon  :-) :-)