# MYSQL Json remove objects from array based on duplicate field

Tags: mysql, json, duplicates

Let's say I try to insert some json data in my column like this:

`[{"key": "a", "value": 1}, {"key":"a", "value": 20}]`

The same key-value object could occur multiple times in the array. But there is only one array in the column.

I would like to have it so that only the first occurence of the same `key` gets entered into the database, in this array.

So the end result would be

`[{"key": "a", "value": 1}]`

Either that or after inserting a separate SQL update statement to filter out all the duplicates.
Is that possible with Mysql 5.7, or 8?

My situation is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954387/mongo-remove-duplicates-in-array-of-objects-based-on-field) question, but for MYSQL

Comment: Does only 2 elements with shown keynames are present in each separate sub-object?

Comment: No it could be multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT test.id, 
       json_parse.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test.id, json_parse.keyname ORDER BY json_parse.rowid) rn
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(val,
                      "$[*]" COLUMNS (rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
                                      keyname VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.key",
                                      keyvalue VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.value")) json_parse
)
SELECT id, JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECTAGG(keyname, keyvalue)) output
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de17680ab3f962359c7c2d40e26a5c8c

If keynames may vary (are dynamic) then gather all present keynames (JSON_KEYS() function) then build correct SQL text and execute as prepared statement. Use above code as a pattern.

Comment: That works excellently, is it possible to make this for 5.7 as well? If not it still helps me a ton. Just wondering if I should upgrade to 8

Comment: *is it possible to make this for 5.7 as well?* No, this code needs at least 8.0.4