# Mongo addtoset each without object duplicate

Tags: mongodb

I have nested array of objects in document:

```
[
  {
    "UserId": new NumberLong("123"),
    "IsActive": true
  }
]
```

I need to have unique by UserId in this array.

For example: this is not valid, array should not have two records with same UserId

```
[
  {
    "UserId": new NumberLong("123"),
    "IsActive": true
  },
 {
    "UserId": new NumberLong("123"),
    "IsActive": false
  }
]
```

I can achieve this by using $ne

```
db.Chats.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("63d244175c4c7b3fe7a01818"),
        "Members.UserId": {$ne: 123}
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            Members: {
                "UserId": 123,
                "IsActive": false
            }
        }
    }
)
```

But how i can achieve this when i use $each?

```
db.Chats.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("63d244175c4c7b3fe7a01818"),
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            Members: {
                $each: [
                    {
                        "UserId": 123,
                        "IsActive": false
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId": 123,
                        "IsActive": true
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: why are you adding duplicates in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo remove duplicates in array of objects based on field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954387/mongo-remove-duplicates-in-array-of-objects-based-on-field)

Comment: The approach with `$addToSet` and `$each` should work. Did you try it?

Comment: @deadshot no, i need adding without duplicates, not removing after

Comment: @lpizzinidev it does not work for me because mongo does not add only if all fields same

Comment: one question, why are you adding the duplicates, if you are doing this from programming language, It would be better remove using some code, instead of doing in the mongo,
as per your question It's not possible to restrict duplicates while adding the document